# Images showing up in wrong place (iOS - mobile ) - wordpress

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress

I have a photography blog, very basic. I just write a blurb, upload the pictures.

Lately I've noticed that on my client iphone 6+ (US based), when visiting the site, some of the pictures from other posts are being placed in other posts that they weren't originally in. Logo and header images replaced with twitter, instagram and FB icon. It's happen with in US only (my client's iphone).  When I look at it on the computer and other mobile devices, everything is right where it should be.

Even its working fine in my iphone 6 (in india).

Anybody else have this problem with mobile? (iphone iOS)

The website is http://www.cuadrilatero.mx/

[image]